# search inside json with grep

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I'm trying to perform a search inside a json. If you type the word exactly as it is on my json, it works otherwise, it doesn't return anything.

For example: My json has a "node": company with the value: Company Name 1

A search for "Company Name 1" works fine and return 1. Any other variation like "company name 1", "Company name 1", "company" returns nothing!

Anyone have a better way of doing this? Here's the function that I'm using:

```
function findByName(compName){
   return $.grep(someVar, function(n, i){
       return n.company == compName;
   });
}
```

Ps: someVar is my json with all data

I'm just trying to make it work like a mysql '%LIKE%' query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just need to adjust both values to same case. Try:

```
function findByName(compName){
   compName = compName.toLowerCase();
   return $.grep(someVar, function(n, i){
       return n.company.toLowerCase() == compName;
   });
}
```

Or for more of a `%LIKE%` use :

```
return n.company.toLowerCase().indexOf(compName) >-1;
```